# WSO2 Micro Integrator Dashboard

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I have a recent installation of wso2 Micro Integrator but I can't find the link to download Micro Integrator Dashboard
Where I can find it?.
Tks

Answer (score 0):

The monitoring dashboard can be downloaded from the below links.

- https://wso2.com/integration/micro-integrator/
- https://wso2.com/integration/

Click on the download button and you will be able to see the resources that are available.
[image]